# How to allocate a large amount of memory for an array?

Tags: c++

The machine has 2 GB and more free memory.
Like the maximum number of elements of the array is limited only by the capabilities of the OS / computer.
That is, having a minimum of 2 GB array can have 2 ^ 32 -1 elements.
But the compiler does not miss. What if I really want an array with 2 ^ 32 elements? :) I tried 2 ^ 31-1, but it does not work ...
OS 64 bit, 6 GB memory, Win32 Console App

```
char * buffer = new char[2147483647]; //Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x004FF998.
```

Comment: You will need to make it an x64 executable rather than WIN32.

Comment: @PaulR Well, and why? Win32 has memory allocation limits?

Comment: WIN32 = 32 bit address space, not all of which is available for large contiguous allocations - see answer below,

Comment: In addition, if you allocate that array on the stack, you'll need to make sure your stack size is big enough. That'll depend entirely on which compiler you're using.

Comment: @Paul Win32 is the Windows Desktop system API, used by both 32 and 64-bit applications. Win32 does not equal 32 bits.

Comment: @rubenvb: sorry if I mangled the terminology - I'm not a Windows person - I always thought that WIN32 pre-dated x86-64 architectures and was 32 bit only, but from what you say it sounds like it has evolved since then. I guess I house have said 32 bit executable or x86 executable,

Comment: @Paul well, I'm not even sure the OP has that distinction straight. I'm a bit pedantic when it comes to this, I did know what you meant, just trying to eradicate the possible misconceptions for future readers ;).

Comment: @rubenvb: I quite understand - I'm an incurable pedant myself - I'll try to be more precise with my Microsoft-related terminology in future, even though it's somewhat alien to me. ;-)

Comment: @rubenvb If we're being _entirely_ technical, [Win32 is the 32-bit API, and Win64 is the 64-bit API](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb496995.aspx).  The changes are almost entirely internal, however, and the actual APIs themselves are basically identical, so everyone just calls them both Win32.  \[[MS prefers that they be called the "Windows API"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff818516.aspx) ("Note that this was formerly called the Win32 API."), but at this point the name Win32 is too firmly ingrained for that to realistically happen.]

Comment: Or in short... Win32 is the 32-bit API, and Win64 is the 64-bit API. As a whole, MS uses the term "Windows API" for both, but everyone else just uses "Win32" because Win64 is more-or-less just a 64-bit backend for the Win32 interface but with a few other small updates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You **CANNOT** get a 2 GB single allocation in a Windows 32-bit application. You'd think that you could, since you can get 3 or 4 GB with /LARGEADDRESSAWARE. But you can't.

The Windows OS [maps some trap pages right around the 2GB mark](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031008-00/?p=42223http://), for catching some kinds of programming errors I assume (actually read the link, I was wrong, it made the Alpha AXP port easier). And that means that your 2 GB array has nowhere it can fit.

So yeah, build your app as a 64-bit application.